# Combine boolean test within if function

Tags: python, pandas, function, if-statement, boolean

I have a dataframe and within it, I am creating a boolean test, then an if-statement/function and then a lambda function to leverage the boolean and a function to write to another column, followed by deleting the boolean test columns.  Is there a way to combine at least the boolean test along with the if statement/function?  There has to be a more efficient way of doing this.

code:

```
df['note1'] = df['child'].isnull()
df['note2'] = df['parent'].isnull()

def b(row):
    if row['note1'] == True:
        return 'check1'
    elif row['note2'] == True:
        return 'check2'
    else:
        return

df['check status'] = df.apply(lambda row: b(row), axis=1)

del df['note1']
del df['note2']
```

The above code serves its purpose and accomplishes my goals, but I am trying to see if there is a way to write this more efficiently and at minimum combine the boolean test with the function.

Thanks,

John

Comment: What happens if both child and parent are null?

Comment: the code is written in such a way where it is not possible for both to be null.  the precursor to this function is taking a dataset from 1 sql query, doing a group by in python, taking a second in the same way from a different server and then joining on multiple columns- so as long as there is a record, either the whole record will be complete or one side of each of the dataset could be null

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.select`:

```
df['check status'] = np.select((df['child'].isnull(), df['parent'].isnull()),
                               ('check1','check2'),
                               np.nan
                              )
```